# DataGrid CellTemplate, Pass DataContext as Command Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which `ItemsSource` is set to `ObservableCollection<ObservablePuls>`.

In last column I have a button, and I would like to bind its `CommandParameter` to `ObservablePuls`. With this code I get null passed as `CommandParameter` and this error:

> BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on
>   'object' ''ObservablePuls' (HashCode=40133923)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem='ObservablePuls'
>   (HashCode=40133923); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

So here is my question: **How do I pass object that is the source of row?**

Here is code of `DataGrid` with button (omitted other columns):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PulsesDataGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableUser.Pulses}"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8"
          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        //... Other columns here

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
                            Margin="10 0 0 0"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=PulsesDataGrid, Path=DataContext.DeleteRowInDataGrid}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext}">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="DeleteForever" />
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Binding `Command` is fine as it is being invoked with a null parameter ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the current DataContext in your DataTemplate (wich is the element displayed in the row) to the CommandParameter by using:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Comment: It was so simple :| And I sit on it for like 2h ... Anyway thx !